# EditText User Input

Tags: android, android-edittext

Hello Android Developers. I did my research and i cant seem to know how to do the following: 1.-I want the user to enter some input (Numbers) in an EditText and i want whatever number he wrote on that edittext to stay there until he taps that edittext, and decides to input another number. What i mean by "staying there" is that when he leaves the app and he comes back in, for the input to be there. Please guide me step by step since im a begginer please.

Note:I would like for it to not have a "save" button, just for the input to stay put.

Comment: When the user exits your app, store the info using one of android's [storage options](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html). When your app is reopened, check if there is an item stored already, and if so put it back into the edittext.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, in your xml for the EditText, make sure to use android:inputType="number" so it is easier for the user to enter numbers.

Second, in onPause() of your Fragment or Activity (whichever holds the EditText, I will assume an Activity for the example code), save your EditText value :

```
String numbers = mET.getText().toString();
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
prefs.edit().putString("numbers", numbers).apply();
```

Then, in onResume(), put it back:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
String numbers = prefs.getString("numbers");
mET.setText(numbers);
```

I hope that helps!

Comment: Hello thanks for your answer. But i have one tiny problem before i can see if is going to work. For some reason i cant have access to the string variable. (I believe its because its Public Static Final). Could you please tell me how to gain access to the string variable?

Comment: @user3893600 You are going to have to show me some code.  I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: @user3893600 Check my updated answer.  I forgot that getDefaultSharedPreferences is a static method of PreferenceManager.  You don't need to implement that method yourself.

Comment: I posted it on answer under the String name, the word name has a yellow line that says i dont have access to the variable. Also onResume in the prefs.getString(""); i get a redline under the text i putted. PLease help. :)